# How to select matching data from two files in linux?

Tags: awk

I have 2 files with lists of genes (and both files having other columns giving different information on the gene lists) I am looking to identify the genes which appear in both files and take the matching gene's information from both files to put into a new file.

For example the data looks like this:

```
File 1
Gene   P value
ACT      0.1
BRCA     0.3
AGT      0.004
UMOD     0.05

File 2
Gene    Tissue
MTHFR   Heart
UMOD.1  Kidney
TP53    Lung
ACT     Lung
```

I am trying to get an output like this:

```
Gene   P value    Tissue
UMOD   0.05       Kidney
ACT    0.1        Lung
```

One issue I have is that one file has matching genes but with additional numbers (e.g. UMOD vs UMOD.1) so even though they are the same gene the gene name isn't exactly the same.

So far to idenitfy which are the matching genes I have tried:

```
cat file1.txt|grep -f file2.txt > temp.txt
```

but the temp file is empty, I am not sure why this hasn't worked or what to do to reach my output, any help would be appreciated.

I have also tried writing something like this (although I know this is all wrong, I can't yet find the syntax for selecting a column from another file, I am in the process of learning awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==1{print;next} {if($1==file2.txt $1) print printf $i""FS; print ""}'  file1txt > temp.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,"",$1)} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1 OFS $2;next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$NF}'  file1  file2
```

As per OP there could be lot of fields in Input_file1 and OP may need few of them, so I am assuming let;s say OP has 15 fields in Input_file1 and need 14 of them first 14 if this is the case then following may help.(since sample is not there so didn't test it but this should work)

```
awk '{sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,"",$1)} FNR==NR{$15="";sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"");a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$NF}'  file1  file2
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it works perfectly. If I had more than 1 additional column of information how would I make it also select the other columns? (I actually have 14 more columns of information) would it be in print a[$1] that I increase the number in the []?

Comment: @DN1, giving example here lets say we have 15 columns(in Input_file1) and you want to have in array value as 14 columns then you could try something like `awk '{sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,"",$1)} FNR==NR{$15="";sub(/[[:space:]]+$,"");a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$NF}'  file1  file2` this is just an example. Give it a shot and let me know then?

Comment: Gives error 'unexpected newline or end of string' with a ^ pointing to after a{print a[$1],$NF}
but that's ok since it may be to do with my data (as it is both text and numeric), and you have given me a lot to learn about and focus on from answering my main question. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @DN1, sorry typo was there use `awk '{sub(/\.[0-9]+$/,"",$1)} FNR==NR{$15="";sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"");a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$NF}'  file1  file2` once?

Answer (score 2):

Another awk (pretty same as @RavinderSingh13's (++) but using `split` and reversed file order to capture `P value` in header output without defining `FS=OFS="\t"`):

```
$ awk '{
    split($1,k,".")         # split $1 on . and store first part to k[1]
}
NR==FNR {
    a[k[1]]=$2              # hash $2 of file2 in a hash, k[1] as key
    next
}
k[1] in a {                 # if k[1] from file1 is found in a hash
    print $0 "\t" a[k[1]]   # output tab-separated
}' file2 file1              # file order reversed
```

Output:

```
Gene    P value Tissue
ACT     0.1     Lung
UMOD    0.05    Kidney
```

**Edit:**

When files have more fields than presented in the OP:

```
$ cat file1
Gene    P value field13
ACT     0.1     val11
BRCA    0.3     val12
AGT     0.004   val13
UMOD    0.05    val14
$ cat file2
Gene    Tissue  field23
MTHFR   Heart   val21
UMOD.1  Kidney  val22
TP53    Lung    val23
ACT     Lung    val24
```

Awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"             # This solution requires field separators set
}
{
    split($1,k,".")         # split $1 on . and store first part (the key) to k[1]
}
NR==FNR {
    $1=""                   # remove unneeded key field from $0
    a[k[1]]=$0              # hash $0 of file2 in a hash, k[1] as key
    next
}
k[1] in a {                 # if k[1] from file1 is found in a hash
    print $0 a[k[1]]        # output tab-separated
}' file2 file1              # file order reversed
```

Output:

```
Gene    P value field13 Tissue  field23
ACT     0.1     val11   Lung    val24
UMOD    0.05    val14   Kidney  val22
```

Comment: This works perfectly as well, thank you for this. If I were to increase the number of columns in file2, would it be changing the =$2 in this code?

Comment: It prints file2 record first then the matching $2 from file1.

Comment: ... so output would be: `Gene    P_value    field3    field4    field5    Tissue`

Comment: Is it possible for it to print out further columns from file1? I have 14 columns and I can only see 1/14 appended to all the columns from file2 in this new file. Apologise if I am misunderstanding something, you have given me enough to go away and learn about regardless, thank you again

Comment: Updated with another solution.

Comment: Yes, provides the other file information as a seperate line when I look at it in excel, but it's been great to learn from, thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `join`. The following examples ignores the `.1` in the gene name and assumes no headers, e.g.:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Output:

```
ACT 0.1 Lung
UMOD 0.05 Kidney
```